# Unable to reset Boolean value - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am once again asking another question about some code for my Simon game I am developing for school.
I have a boolean value set to false, the game first checks for a keypress and then sets the value to true. If the user gets the incorrect game sequence, it should then reset the value back to false. For some reason my code isn't changing the boolean back and forth when it is needed and I am not so sure why.

```
/*************VARIABLES*************/
//store colors
var buttonColors = [
    "green", //0
    "red", //1
    "yellow", //2
    "blue" //3
]
//Game Pattern Storage
var gamePattern = [ /*Added From nextSequence*/ ];
var userClicks = [ /* Added from userClickHistory*/ ];

var level = 0;
var gameOn = false;

/******************BASIC FUNCTIONS*********************/

/*AWAIT KEYPRESS TO BEGIN GAME*/
$(document).keypress(function () {
    if (!gameOn) {
        nextSequence();
        $(`#level-title`).text(`Level: ` + level);
        var gameOn = true;
    }
});

//log user clicks after nextSequence() has executed, check the userClicks vs gamePattern using checkAnswer(lastInArray)
$(`.btn`).click(function () {
    var buttonClicked = $(this).attr(`id`);
    userClicks.push(buttonClicked);
    animate(buttonClicked);
    playSound(buttonClicked);

    checkAnswer(userClicks.length - 1);
});


function checkAnswer(usersLastClick) {
    //if the gamePatterns last call is equal to the users last click
    if (gamePattern[usersLastClick] === userClicks[usersLastClick]) {
        console.log("success");
        //if the userClicks and the gamePatterns lengths are equal, call nextSequence()
        if (userClicks.length === gamePattern.length) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nextSequence();
                //update the titles level indicator
                $(`#level-title`).text(`Level: ` + level);
            }, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        $(`#level-title`).text(`You have made it to level ` + level + '! Hit enter to try again')
        //play sound for incorrect click
        var wrongSound = new Audio('sounds/wrong.mp3');
        wrongSound.play();
        console.log("wrong")
        console.log(`[` + userClicks + `]`);
        console.log(`[` + gamePattern + `]`);
        reset();
    }

}
/************* NEXT SEQUENCE TO PROGRESS GAME *********/
function nextSequence() {
    userClicks = [];
    level++;
    console.log(level);

    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
    randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
    animate(randomChosenColor);
    playSound(randomChosenColor);
}

function reset() {
    var level = 0;
    var gamePattern = [];
    var gameOn = false;
}


/******************** SOUNDS AND ANIMATIONS*************************************/

//buttons animations
function animate(clickedButton) {
    $(`#` + clickedButton).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
};

//Play a sound in correlation to randomChosenColor
function playSound(color) {
    var sound = new Audio('sounds/' + color + '.mp3');
    sound.play();
};
```

When my code runs, nowhere inside does the boolean value change, and I have also noticed that my arrays aren't being emptied when the game is suppose to reset as well. When I console.log(gameOn) it always returns false, whether the game is running or not.

Comment: You declare gameOn twice. Javascript variables are scoped by function. When you set gameOn to true you have ```var gameOn = true;```, this is inside an anonymous function, because of ```var``` you are declaring a new variable, not referencing the outer variable. Get rid of the second var.

Comment: You're redeclaring `gameOn` as a local variable in your keypress handler. Remove the `var`.

Comment: You are declaring the `var gameOn =` every time and not reusing the same variable.  In essence, creating a new one every time

Comment: `if (!gameOn) {
        nextSequence();
       .....
       var gameOn = true;
    }`

why are you declaring the gameOn variable again. You can just use the variable directly **gameOn=...**, since it is declared in the outer scope and available in the inner scope

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks guys, didn't realize I didn't require the var each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$(document).keypress` function try taking out the "`var`" before "`gameOn = true`".  I think now it's as if you're declaring a new variable, when you really want to change the global `gameOn` var.

Comment: I somehow had a huge learning gap towards this problem when declaring my variables. Probably partially due to the fact that I originally learned Python and Ruby quite a long time ago, and declaring variables is very different, and partially due to the confusion of trying to learn ES6 before learning previous vanilla Javascript versions. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!gameOn) { nextSequence(); ..... var gameOn = true; }`

Don't declare the gameOn variable again. You can just use the variable directly **gameOn=...**, since it is declared in the outer scope of the function and available in the inner scope

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't declare gameOn twice and it should work out.

But I've been reading more and more about the "evils" of global variables in JavaScript especially, since a global namespace means anything can edit these variables, even other scripts.

The solution a lot of people seem to gravitate toward is to wrap variables in an object, like so:

```
var globals = {
buttonColors: [ "green", "red", "yellow", "blue"],
gamePattern: [ /*Added From nextSequence*/ ],
userClicks: [ /* Added from userClickHistory*/ ],
level: 0,
gameOn: false,
}
```

Then, just use "globals.buttonColors" for example to reference your variables.

Not 100% necessary if you plan to keep the scope small, but a good practice to get into regardless.

Comment: I'll have to look into this a bit, it seems cleaner and would definitely help to avoid accidentally re assigning like I did

Comment: Yeah, I went looking at one point and this was eye-opening for me: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp

Was one of those "Oh...whoops!" moments as I scrambled to change a lot of things I had created in the past.